# How to remove example.com/example/"index" in grocery crud?

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I am using the GroceryCRUD CodeIgniter library. I just want to remove the "/index" in my site's url for example: having this link `dev.example.com/example/index/InfoTable` to `dev.example.com/example/InfoTable`.

It affects my other links because if I want to go to other page example: `dev.example.com/example/Maps`, it redirects to error 404 because the url is in groceryCrud-like format(`dev.example.com/example/InfoTable/index/Maps`) and it also happens to all my normal links every time I access the grocery crud links and buttons.

Comment: do you try changing .htacss file

Comment: yes, from the suggested .htaccess code from grocery crud and to others related to it. I mean i tried anything, the index from the my controller is in the effect of .htaccess given from grocery crud, not actually the index of grocery crud. In my observation of the grocery crud code, near state_url() function, if you remove the 'index', the crud wont work, and it is also stated at the comments. Thanks for your suggestion, it would make our convo healthy if you suggest more ideas aside of what you've give today. Kudos!
(sorry for the grammar, hope you understand)

Comment: You can use the method:`set_crud_url_path` http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_crud_url_path

Comment: tnx so much @JohnSkoumbourdis for the answer, i'll give it a shot later... btw, i tried ur suggestion about the topic with the .htaccess and it's not working... i will throw an update when i try this later... tnx so much :)

Comment: it worked @JohnSkoumbourdis, thanks sir, kudos! (y)

Comment: but when i remove the `index` in the url, the add button cant redirect to add page/section(ex: $crud->set_crud_url_path('InfoTable/','/InfoTable');).

but this `$crud->set_crud_url_path('InfoTable/index','/InfoTable');` worked.

i actually rely on my UI when the library performs crud since the default UI theme cant get the cache on the library, it keeps as a default UI theme.

Comment: @JohnSkoumbourdis plz help :(

Comment: Yes, grocery CRUD is relying on the URL for editing/add/delete... e.t.c. so it is not possible to change all the URLs. The method set_crud_url_path is mainly useful for the first list page to work correctly with your routes (e.g. remove the index) but for all the other operations you will need to have the /index at the URL. I am sorry for that.

Comment: @JohnSkoumbourdis i knew it :(. i have another question, can i modify the menu links when i redirect to add, edit and view section of grocery crud? How can i do it? when i try `set_crud_url_path('<my desired menu link>','<my table list>')`, it doesn't work. Ex: my desired menu link -> "`example.com/Map` **or** `example.com/InfoTable`" **but** in the add/edit/view section it appears like `example.com/InfoTable/InfoTable` and `example.com/InfoTable/Maps`. btw, i have 2 menus. Hope you answer this ASAP, thanks in advance.

Comment: And @JohnSkoumbourdis, can i modify the header, scripts and css tags when i direct to add/edit/view section of grocery crud? i already try the `set_js()` and `set_css()` but it appears that my UI broke in add/edit/view section. Sorry for the long confusions.

Comment: I don't know how related the subsequent questions are here, but I would advise that if they could be asked as a new question, please do so. Comments are not searchable on Stack Overflow, which means that any new Q&A hidden in comments will not be useful for future readers who might otherwise benefit from them.